# how to fetch result using two table in database with atleast condition

Tags: mysql, oracle

Have two table in mysql database with table1 and table2,

```
 table1
         id      marks      hodname
         1       10%         abc
         2       20%         tec
         3       50%         med
         4       60%         abc
         5       70%         tec
```

```
 table2
         uid            hodname
         1                abc
         2                tec
         3                med
```

I want to fetch hodname with marks but condition is if any hod have marks below 30% should not be in result. Only hod with above 30% i want in result if he is having alteast on marks below 30% then don't consider in result.Please help me out with mysql query for this.
Result should be

```
 table2
         marks            hodname
         50%                med
```

Comment: thanks to all, this is the sample database . Actually i want to filter only name with pass percentage . So table2 contains name only but all the details i have in table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select table1.marks, table2.hodname
from table2 
inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.uid
where marks > 30
```

or if your `marks` is a string with percentage symbol:

```
select table1.marks, table2.hodname
from table2 
inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.uid
where replace(marks,'%','')*1 > 30
```

Comment: Hey thanks......and sorry this is not giving me correct result if i insert 20% for med ...it shud give blank output..because he is having below 35 % marks once...how to do that